# ASP Net Core Missing Buttons For DataTable Using Content Delivery Network

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

**My goal is to do the following in ASP Net Core:**

1. Create a jQuery DataTable
2. Show the number of entries in the
   datatable
3. Make sure the user is able to export the dataset in excel,
   csv, pdf, and copy the results Have all of the references installed
   using the CDN (Content Delivery Network) in ASP Net Core

**My question**

Are there any tutorials on youtube, or any articles that describe how to do this?

I am following this tutorial https://youtube.com/watch?v=Pt7O-X9vmjw The problem is that, although I am able to create a datatable using his tutorial, the following problems continue:

The number of entries in the datatable is missing.

The user is unable to export the dataset in excel, csv, pdf, and copy the results

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for weeks. My suspicion is that bootstrap, which is already installed in the layout, is causing these problems. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Sandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement of using DataTables with [data export functionality](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html), you can refer to the following example.

In _Layout.cshtml

*CSS references*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

*JS references*

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

In View page

*Add required JS references of data export plug-ins*

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#myTable").dataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: This works great!  The only other missing element is the dropdown - which lets the use select the number of rows to display per page.  Any idea how to get the dropdown working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130969/jquery-datatable-show-entries-dropdown-is-not-displaying-default-value-in-fire

Comment: `The only other missing element is the dropdown - which lets the use select the number of rows to display per page.` To display both dropdown and data exporting buttons, you can set `dom` option to `'lBfrtip'`.

Comment: @Lisa: In order to show the Dropdown that allows the user the select the number of rows per page, you can set the jQuery DataTable's property **[lengthChange](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange)** to true, like this `"lengthChange": true`

Comment: `This works perfectly` Hi @Lisa, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to accept above reply as answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer - many thanks for your help Fei!